# calculating complex numbers $ (1+i\sqrt{3})^{2017} + (1-i\sqrt{3})^{2017} $

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following 
$ (1+i\sqrt{3})^{2017} + (1-i\sqrt{3})^{2017}  $
and I  have to find the answser.

I think the answer might be $ 2^{2017}  $ but I don't know how to find

Comment: Are you familiar with polar notation for complex numbers? i.e. converting from $x + iy$ to $r \mbox{cis} \theta$ (or $r e^{i\theta}$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $$(1+\sqrt3i)^3=(1-\sqrt3i)^3=-8$$ and $2017\equiv1(\mod3).$

I got $$2\cdot(-8)^{672}=2^{2017}.$$

Answer (score 1):

First, convert these to polar form, so $1+i\sqrt{3}=2e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}},$ and $1-i\sqrt{3}=2e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}},$
then raise these exponential terms to the desired power, and proceed with the computation, using the identity 
$$e^{it}=\cos(t)+i\sin(t).$$

Comment: using $e^{i2\pi n}=1$ might help too